# geometry auto-scaling not working to fit text on value change

Tags: aframe

I'm having trouble with the auto-scale of the geometry to fit the text. It works well when the entity is created, like so:

```
    <a-entity id="testtext"
              position="0 0 0" 
              geometry="primitive: plane; height: auto; width: auto"
              material="color: blue"
              text="width: 5; value: not a long text">
    </a-entity>
```

But the geometry stays as is if I update the text value by executing in the console the following command:

```
document.querySelector('#testtext').setAttribute('text','value', 'new text is long enough to wrap and force multiline content')
```

This results on a multiline content that overflows in height the geometry. My expectation was to see the plane resize to fit the multiline text.

Am I missing some attribute or setting or trick?

Thanks in advance for your help